# Standard errors for population rates based on survey data

Tags: stata, standard-error, survey-weights

I have survey data that includes a random sample of emergency rooms in the United States. Each observation has a sampling weight that allows me to estimate the  number of cases for a particular disease nationally. While I can get the standard error for this estimate, I also want to calculate the population rate, i.e. cases of disease per 100,000 people. I am using census data to calculate:

> disease cases / (population for that demographic) * 100000

But how can I also get the standard error for the population rate? I tried:

> std err for case count / (population for that demographic) * 100000

When using that formula, however, standard error grows when that population (based on census data) is small, even if the initial standard error for national case count is low. That doesn't seem like it makes sense and suggests I don't know what I'm doing.

I would appreciate any insight. I am using Stata, but even knowing the theory behind this might help me figure it out.

Here is just an example of an annual count:

```
. svy: tab year, count se format(%9.0g) 
(running tabulate on estimation sample) 
Number of strata = 1 Number of obs = 11321 
Number of PSUs = 62 
Population size = 655770.73 Design df = 61 
--------------------‌​-------------- 
year      | count    se 
----------+---------‌​-------------- 
2004      | 73282.14 14066.59 
2005      | 68625.86 12901.92 
... 
2010      | 90914.29 18704.43 
2011      | 96551.95 20952.36 
Total     | 655770.7
```

Comment: The pop rate calculation is not actual Stata code. Please show us the exact command that you typed along with the output of `svyset`.

Comment: Here is just an example of an annual count:

`. svy: tab year, count se format(%9.0g)`
(running tabulate on estimation sample)

Number of strata   =         1                  Number of obs      =     11321
Number of PSUs     =        62                  Population size    = 655770.73
Design df          =        61

----------------------------------
     year |      count          se
----------+-----------------------
     2004 |   73282.14    14066.59
     2005 |   68625.86    12901.92
...
     2010 |   90914.29    18704.43
     2011 |   96551.95    20952.36
    Total |   655770.7

Comment: I then did the population standardization in Excel, although there may be a Stata command for that as well (I haven't found it yet).

Comment: Have you considered fitting a `poisson` model with population as an exposure? You can use the `svy` with that as far as I know.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Turns out the solution is to use the `collapse` command to get the data into a yearly format (rather than individual observations) and then to use `dstdize`, the commend for direct standardization.

Comment: I'd be worried that your standard errors on the rates are not right. It does not look to me like `dstdize` actually produces standard errors at all. The standard error does not "grow" anywhere... if you fix the counts and their standard errors, and fiddle with the population size, then a small population implies high rate, and with that comes higher variance if you think about say Poisson in which variance = rate.